# Retaining Parameters on Website to pass to Landing Page which expects a parameter

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a landing page setup that accepts a ‘campaign’ parameter from the URL and the landing page takes this parameter and sends it accordingly into SalesForce.

This all works great when we are directly calling the landing page and including the parameter.

Our scenario is we are using Google Adwords that contains the link to our website and it is here we add the parameter (can be different) to the URL to a page on our website (not the landing page). However clearly when it hits our website the parameter is lost because the website doesn’t know what to do with it.

What we would like to happen is the user can look around the website, but when they click on the link to the landing page, the ‘campaign’ parameter will get added on the URL and the landing page works as it should.
So the question is what is the best way to retain the campaign parameter on the website?

I was hoping ET had some sort of snippet of code we could use, but I’m assuming it’s some sort of JavaScript that needs built out.

If anyone has any ideas or experience with this your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
var Campaign = getParam('campaign');
var yourURL= 'YourLandingPageURL?campaign='+Campaign;
```

Hope this will help you !